# How does a process of optimization go with tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I have simple graph in `tensorflow`

```
(1) X = tf.Variable(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(1, 3), name="X", initial_value=np.array([[1,2,3]]))
(2) y = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(X))  - 2 * tf.reduce_sum(tf.sin(tf.square(X)))
(3) training_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.3).minimize(y)
```

Here's the code for 5 steps of gradient descent:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for i in range(5):
        (4) *res, _ = sess.run(fetches=[X, y, training_op])
        print(res)

[array([[1., 2., 3.]], dtype=float32), 13.006426]
[array([[ 1.0483627 , -0.76874477, -2.080069  ]], dtype=float32), 4.9738936]
[array([[ 0.9910337 , -1.0735381 ,  0.10702228]], dtype=float32), -1.3677568]
[array([[ 1.0567244 , -0.95272505,  0.17122723]], dtype=float32), -1.3784065]
[array([[ 0.978967  , -1.0848547 ,  0.27387527]], dtype=float32), -1.4229481]
```

I'm trying to figure out how its optimization process goes. Could you please explain it step by step?
I thought it should be like this:

1. Evaluate X (1)
2. Evaluate y (2)
3. Calculate gradient and make a step  [image: $ X = X - \gamma (3?)$] (3) (as [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/train/Optimizer) it says "Calling minimize() takes care of both computing the gradients and applying them to the variables."
4. Then yield all requested in `fetches` variables (4)

   But the output shows that at first `run` yields initial values, so I'm confused...

`tf` version == '1.15.0'

Thank you in advance!

upd1. If I change the order in `fetches` list, the output is still the same.

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for i in range(5):
        _, *res = sess.run(fetches=[training_op, X, y])
        print(res)
[array([[1., 2., 3.]], dtype=float32), 13.006426]
[array([[ 1.0483627 , -0.76874477, -2.080069  ]], dtype=float32), 4.9738936]
[array([[ 0.9910337 , -1.0735381 ,  0.10702228]], dtype=float32), -1.3677568]
[array([[ 1.0567244 , -0.95272505,  0.17122723]], dtype=float32), -1.3784065]
[array([[ 0.978967  , -1.0848547 ,  0.27387527]], dtype=float32), -1.4229481]
```

upd2. A slight modification of the answer by @thushv89 does what I initially expected to see:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for i in range(2):
        res = sess.run(fetches=[X, y])
        print('Variables before the step', res)
        sess.run(training_op)
        res = sess.run(fetches=[X, y])
        print('Variables after the step', res)
        print()
Variables before the step [array([[1., 2., 3.]], dtype=float32), 13.006426]
Variables after the step [array([[ 1.0483627 , -0.76874477, -2.080069  ]], dtype=float32), 4.9738936]

Variables before the step [array([[ 1.0483627 , -0.76874477, -2.080069  ]], dtype=float32), 4.9738936]
Variables after the step [array([[ 0.9910337 , -1.0735381 ,  0.10702228]], dtype=float32), -1.3677568]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `fetches=[X, y, training_op]`. These don't respect the order (At least you shouldn't expect `sess.run()` to respect the order). Which means, all of the,

- Evaluates `X` (so the `training_op` hasn't happened yet)
- Evaluate `y` (still the `training_op` hasn't happened yet)
- Executes `training_op` (now, `X` and `y` have changed).

gets executed and then the results are fetched. If you want the variable `X` to change first,

### Option 1: Breaking the `sess.run()` function

```
r1 = sess.run(X)
_, r2 = sess.run(fetches=[training_op, y])
print(r1,r2)
```

### Option 2: Using a separate `tf.Variable` with `tf.control_dependencies`

```
X = tf.Variable(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(1, 3), name="X", initial_value=np.array([[1,2,3]]))
prevX = tf.Variable(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(1, 3), name="prevX", initial_value=np.array([[1,2,3]]))
y = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(X))  - 2 * tf.reduce_sum(tf.sin(tf.square(X)))
assign_op = tf.assign(prevX, X)
with tf.control_dependencies([assign_op]):
  training_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.3).minimize(y)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init)
    for i in range(5):

        *res, _ = sess.run(fetches=[prevX, y, training_op])
        print(res)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunally, it did not help. The output is the same.

Comment: @elfinorr, let me have a look. I had a working example of this.

Comment: I think you're correct. I think I had this wrongly figured out. It does not respect the order. There's two ways to force it to respect the order, (1) use `tf.control_dependencies` and (2) break your `sess.run()` manually to which order you want it to respect. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the update! I think the Option 1 you suggested is what makes sence. It looks like if we fetch variables and perform an optimization step in one `sess.run`, then `tf` firstly yields values of variables and only then does the step. The result I expected to get is like if we do `sess.run(training_op); res = sess.run(fetches=[X, y])`.